# Motherboard replacement issue

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, hardware-rec

I have this motherboard that died - [MSI P67AC43B3](http://msi.com/product/motherboard/P67AC43.html#hero-overview)

and I need to replace it, but it seems there are no new motherboards that support s1155 and P67 chipset. I have an i5-2400 processor and an Asus GTX 560-ti. Which new motherboard do I need to be a good replacement? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The i5-2400 will work with pretty much any socket 1155 motherboard, so you can look at the boards that were released with [SandyBridge CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155#Original_Sandy_Bridge_chipsets) — for example, H61, H67, Z68 — as well as those that were released for [IvyBridge CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155#Ivy_Bridge_chipsets), such as B75, H77, Z77.

Most board manufacturers have a CPU compatibility list for each board, so if you find a particular board, you should be able to confirm by searching for the make/model.

Given that they're not made any more, finding a "good" replacement might be tricky. As long as the motherboard has all the ports and sockets you need, it should do the job. They all at least have a PCIe x16 slot for your GPU. Some low-end boards only have 2 RAM slots — if you have more sticks than that it would be a problem. Most DDR3 RAM will work with any board, but you can also try and confirm RAM compatibility either with the motherboard or RAM manufacturer's compatibility lists. Other things that you need — like the number of USB ports; fan headers; PCI/PCIe slot combinations — and what sized board your case will fit might lead you to accept or reject a replacement.

(If you had an overclockable 'K' CPU it would be more difficult, because the Z68 or Z77 are the best choice there).

2nd hand is most likely a cost-effective option if you can find one. Some socket 1155 boards are still available at online stores, so you could check Newegg, Amazon, and similar places. Alternatively, you could call a few local computers stores to see if by chance they've got old stock.

As an example of the process: here's a listing for the [Gigabyte B75M-D3H at Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007R9CRGW). The [CPU support list](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4150#) shows that the i5-2400 is supported. It has 4 RAM slots, and after the GPU is in will have a PCI and PCIe slot free. It is only micro-ATX sized, so smaller than your current board, but most cases that support ATX will fit a micro-ATX board too.

If you change the make and model of the board, you may have difficulty booting your OS with the updated board. This depends what OS you're using, and how different the replacement board is as far as drivers go. Windows traditionally hates hardware being replaced, and may refuse to boot; if you were using, say, Linux it would most likely just work. So keep that in mind that some recovery or worst-case reinstall of the OS might be required. This might lead you to try and match the chipsets as @Paul mentioned.

<sub>As an aside, I assume you've confirmed it's certainly the motherboard, and not something else like a dead power supply, that's causing your problems?</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your big reply, i'm having red horizontal lines over my screen when booting and i've already ruled out the monitor, cable and a video card, so it's probably the motherboard, i'll try to confirm it on Monday. So these H61 or H67 will do for sure ?)

Comment: Will this work Asus H61M-K (s1155, Intel H61, PCI-Ex16) or MSI H61M-P31/W8 ?

Comment: You happened to pick two I can't answer for sure. Asus list the i5-2400S but not the i5-2400 in the compatibility list. Probably an oversight, since there should be no reason it wouldn't work, but maybe not? I can't get the MSI page to display the CPU support list for whatever reason. Based on specs both should work afaik. Be aware since they're low-end boards they're both somewhat limited, only 2 RAM slots, that kind of thing.

Comment: Yeah i see that they have only 2 slots, i'll have to sacrifice my 4 gbs, cause i have 2x4 and 2x2. What do yoy mean by low-end ? You mean they are too cheap ?

Comment: They are cheap comparatively, not that it's a bad thing, it's just the feature set they have to hit the price point.

Answer (score -1):

Since your CPU is an LGA1155, any motherboard with that socket will do. They will be harder to find with time but it is still possible to find and buy one today.

You're putting a GTX 560 inside so I guess max performance isn't your goal. I would stick with the ASUS brand and P67 chipset. Personally, I'd go with an ASUS P8P67, for example (would it be LE, Plus or anything else, go for the best price). One more issue you could have: if you have more than 2 RAM sticks, make sure your motherboard has 4 RAM slots.

Comment: @Ash is right. Keeping with the MSi brand or at least the exact same chipset 'could' save you a reinstall. Depends on your point of view. I would reinstall just to make sure everything's perfect, but that's me. Maybe you prefer keeping that mommy's Windows up and running :)

Comment: Supply of that model in the shop that i will be buying from ended. Which socket it the successor now of s1155 i can't seem to understand, so i can plug in my video card and processor ?